# How to save a file on Android? (Firemonkey)

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

How can I save a file locally on an Android device,
using Delphi (XE5, Firemonkey)?

Something as simple as

```
  Memo.Lines.SaveToFile('test.txt')
```

does not seem to work.
It results in the following error message:

"Cannot create file "/test.txt". Not a directory."

Comment: When you say locally, what do you mean?  SDCard (internal/external?), private data?  Other?  You cannot create a file in `/` without root and permissions.

Comment: I was hoping that I could just write in the 'current directory' of the internal storage (whereever that may be).
Note that I didn't specify the backslash before the file name. I am surprised that it seems to try to write in the root.

Comment: I also tried this path: "/Android/data/com.embarcadero.TestLocalStorage/files/" (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html seems to indicate that that may be a proper location for Internal Storage). But got the same result

Answer (score 19, accepted):

According to the document [Creating an Android App](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE5/en/Creating_an_Android_App), get the documents path like this:

```
System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim + 'myfile';
```

Comment: That's what I was looking for.
Thanks a lot!
BTW: in this case: no specific permissions are necessary.

Comment: Don't you want to use Path.Combine or whatever the function is

Answer (score 11):

Instead of using `System.SysUtils.PathDelim`, you may use

```
System.IOUtils.TPath.Combine(System.IOUtils.tpath.getdocumentspath,'test.txt');
```

`Combine` chooses between the windows `\` and the Linux `/`

`System.IOUtils` must be used in this line instead of setup in the uses clause because there are probably more Tpath initials.

Answer (score 2):

GetHomePath, return a string with the path.
-> 'data/data//files'

You can to use:

```
Memo.Lines.SaveToFile(format('%s/test.txt', [GetHomePath]));
```

Or this form

```
Memo.Lines.SaveToFile(GetHomePath + '/test.txt');
```

Answer (score 2):

on my device (and presumably all android devices?) GetHomePath incorrectly gives me  /storage/emulated/0/... whereas I need /storage/sdcard0/... to get to the storage visible in Windows Explorer via USB.

so the full path to my files may be
'/storage/sdcard0/Android/data/com.embarcadero.(my app name)/files/'

Presumably if you have a plug in SD card this might be sdcard1 or whatever.

You can list the contents of your device storage folder with code like this

```
  P := '/storage/';
  if (FindFirst(P + '*', faAnyFile, Sr) = 0) then
  repeat
    Memo1.Lines.Add(Sr.Name);
  until (FindNext(Sr) <> 0);
  FindClose(Sr);
```

On my device this gives me:

sdcard0
usb
emulated

then change S when you want to explore subfolders

Note that the files folder gets emptied each time you recompile and deploy.