# Delphi save text file on Android

Tags: android, delphi, delphi-xe5

I have to upload a text file on my android project and so I used the `IdFTP`. This is the code:

```
Button2.Enabled:=False;
Label5.Text:='Uploading...';

Memo1.Lines.Add(Edit1.Text+':'+ComboBox1.Items.Text);
Memo1.SaveToFile('filehost.txt');

try
 IdFTP1.Connect;
  // I set the host, password and username
 IdFTP1.Put('filehost.txt');
finally
 IdFTP1.Disconnect;
```

I am having a problem because when I run the app on my Samsung (Android 2.3) I have an error that says `Cannot create file "/filehost.txt". Not a directory`.

I must save the content of that Memo1 in my Android device and then upload it using the IdFTP. How can I do it avoiding that error?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to save a file on Android? (Firemonkey)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857936/how-to-save-a-file-on-android-firemonkey)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't write to the root folder.  Use [`TPath`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE5/en/System.IOUtils.TPath) to find a writable folder, such as from `TPath.GetTempPath()` or `TPath.GetDocumentsPath()`.

Alternatively, do not use a file at all.  `TIdFTP.Put()` has an overloaded version that uploads a `TStream` instead of a file, eg:

```
var
  MS: TMemoryStream;
begin
  MS := TMemoryStream.Create;
  try
    Memo1.Lines.SaveToStream(MS);
    MS.Position := 0;
    ...
    IdFTP1.Put(MS, 'filehost.txt');
    ...
  finally
    MS.Free;
  end;
end;
```