# Delphi - Deploying and accessing local files on Android

Tags: android, delphi

When I run Android app it's working fine. Problem when I change some data and click button 'Save Changes'. Then again run App it's showing old data.

I need My App load me saved one.

**I'm using Delphi Xe8->Multi-Device App.**
[image: Using]

For Android, I set the Remote Path to assets\internal -->.\assets\internal\
[image: Deployment]

**Save Changes button Code:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
CDS.SaveToFile(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'users.cds');
end;
```

**OnCreate Code:**

```
procedure TForm1.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin
CDS.LoadFromFile(TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'users.cds'); //Embarcadero\Studio\Projects\example\Client\Android\Debug\Client\assets\internal
end;
```

Comment: Have you tried displaying on your form (or in the debugger) the value of the expression `TPath.GetDocumentsPath + PathDelim + 'users.cds'` and confirmed that it is the same  in `FormCreate` and `Button1Click`?

Comment: yes, they're the same[FormCreate and ButtonClick].

Comment: Well, the CDS's SaveToFile and LoadFromFile normally work without any problem, but I've only ever used them under Windows.  Maybe your problem is Android-specific, to do with user-permissions or something.  Can you save a TMemo's contents to the same folder and reload it and save changes to it, etc?

Comment: Btw, you might take a look at this q: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857936/how-to-save-a-file-on-android-firemonkey and in particular, Leslie Kaye's answer.

Comment: I put On Memo1.lines.add(TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'users.cds')).

I got this path: /data/data/com.embarcadero.Client/files/users.cds

Comment: Sorry, that's not what I meant.  Can you save and reload the contents of a TMemo to the same folder?

Comment: You have not shown how you're changing the data in the CDS.

Comment: i'm not sure does it matter but the `Remote path` is usually `assets\internal\ `

Comment: Dear @ MartynA . I need your help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42431336/delphi-how-to-call-actionlist-on-button?noredirect=1#comment72008357_42431336

Answer (score 3):

```
AppPath := TPath.GetHomePath;
FileName := TPath.Combine(AppPath, 'users.cds');
```