# Delphi- How to Call ActionList on button click?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I'm making a multi-device application in Delphi XE8 which uses LiveBindings to a dataset.

There are a number of LB-specific Actions for FMX, including TFMXBindNavigateDelete.  I'm trying to use this in a button-click handler like this:

**Button Click Code:**

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if cdsOrdersSTATUS.Value='READY' then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Your Order Is Already READY/PENDING!');
  end
  else
  begin
    TAction(ActionList1.Actions[0]).Execute; //Not working,why?
  end;
end;
```

The first (and only) item in ActionList1's Actions is my FMXBindNavigateDelete1.

The problem is, even if the code `TAction(ActionList1.Actions[0]).Execute` executes, the current dataset record is **not** deleted, so apparently
TFMXBindNavigateDelete's Action has no effect.  Why is this, and how can I make it work?

**Pic. ActionList1:**

[image: ActionList]

Comment: Changing the `Name` of an Action does not invoke the action, only change its identifier. What's wrong with simply assigning the Action to the `TButton.Action` property and let the button invoke it automatically? What are you really trying to accomplish?

Comment: if cdsOrdersSTATUS.Value='READY' then
  begin
  ShowMessage('Your Order Is Already READY/PENDING!');
  end
else
  begin
  ActionList1.Actions[0].Name:='LiveBindingsBindNavigateDelete1';
  end;

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say. If you just want to invoke the `OnExecute` event of an Action, call its `Execute()` method.

Comment: @Dear Remy I need to put On Button manual code to call ActionList.action[0]. how to call on Button by code?

Comment: if .....then
begin
//
end
else
begin
ActionList1.Actions[0].Name:='LiveBindingsBindNavigateDelete1';   //this is not working ?
end;

Comment: why do you keep focusing on setting the action's Name? That has nothing to do with your issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, I think this is a good question and doesn't deserve the downvote.

I can reproduce your problem. I put two buttons on the FMX form.  I set
Button1's OnClick to your `Button1Click` and Button2's `Action` to `LiveBindingsBindNavigateDelete1`.

Clicking Button2 pops up the standard 'Delete record?' confirmation and deletes the current record
if I answer "Yes", as expected.

However, when clicking Button1, even if your `else` block executes, the 'Delete record?' confirmation
does **not** appear, so the record has no chance of being deleted.

The reason is in the code

```
function TCustomAction.Execute: Boolean;
begin
  Result := False;
  if Supported and not Suspended then
  begin
    Update;
    if Enabled and AutoCheck then
      if (not Checked) or (Checked and (GroupIndex = 0)) then
        Checked := not Checked;
    if Enabled then
      Result := ((ActionList <> nil) and ActionList.ExecuteAction(Self)) or
        ((Application <> nil) and Application.ExecuteAction(Self)) or inherited Execute or
        ((Application <> nil) and Application.ActionExecuteTarget(Self));
  end;
end;
```

The `Enabled` property seems by default to be set to False during the call to
`Update` so the `if Enabled then ...` never executes.  I haven't managed to find
a way to get `Enabled` set to True during the call to `Update`.  Perhaps someone else knows how to do that.

In the case of `Button2`, execution then passes to `TComponent.ExecuteAction` and
it is the call to `Action.ExecuteTarget(Self)` in it which results in the
record-deletion routine executing.

So, from that, your problem seemed to me to become how to adjust the code so that
`TComponent.ExecuteAction` gets executed, in other words, how to associate the
`Action` with a component.  The answer was fairly obvious.

All that's needed is this

```
procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
 if cdsOrdersSTATUS.Value='READY' then
  begin
    ShowMessage('Your Order Is Already READY/PENDING!');
  end
  else
  begin
    Button1.ExecuteAction(LiveBindingsBindNavigateDelete1);  //  <- this works
    //LiveBindingsBindNavigateDelete1.Execute; //Not working,why?
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Perhaps you could rewrite the question to make it really clear, Martyn

Comment: @DavidHeffernan:  I have had a go.

Comment: @ MartynA. I need your help !

I create a multi-device application Server&Client.
In a Server Side I've folder[images/] where location Folder: SERVER/Win32/Debug/images/.png,.png,.png....
I'd like to send Folder[images/] or inside folder[images/.png,.png,.png] All images to Client through App tethering BY ONE click. 
To Client Location: CLIENT/Win32/Debug/images/
sO, I'd like to get through to this folder[images/].
How to do that? plz need your help.

Comment: @AlexKirov:  Sorry, I don't understand what you are asking, and in any case I couldn't post an "answer" to a comment.  I suggest you ask a new SO q about it.

Comment: @ MartynA http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42466503/how-to-send-all-images-to-client-specific-folder-by-one-click-using-app-tetherin

Answer (score 0):

I didn't understand exactly what you wanted to do but if you trigger the action by it's index, you can do something like this:

```
TAction(ActionList1.Actions[0]).Execute;
```

Comment: @Dear Sima TAction(ActionList1.Actions[0]).Execute; not working.by the way  I update my quation!

Comment: @AlexKirov "*not working*" in what way exactly? You need to be more specific. What behavior are you expecting? What is it doing instead?

Comment: @AlexKirov is the Action you are trying to invoke named `LiveBindingsBindNavigateDelete1` in the ActionList to begin with? If so, then you can just call `LiveBindingsBindNavigateDelete1.Execute()` instead of `TAction(ActionList1.Actions[0]).Execute()`. Don't rely on the Action's index in the list.