# Cannot get correct path to Documents folder on Android using Delphi 10.3

Tags: delphi-10.3-rio

When I use this code

path := system.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath;

I get the following value for "path":

/data/user/0/com.embarcadero./files

This makes no sense to me at all.

Comment: I think you are looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18857936/how-to-save-a-file-on-android-firemonkey

Comment: I have already read and tried that approach, and it fails.  I want to be able to read the contents of the Documents folder, not read and write into a sandboxed folder.  All of this was working under 10.2 Tokyo, but no longer works as it once did.

Comment: I can see the Documents folder using a variety of tools on the Android device.  One tool claims the path is '/Documents'.  Another claims the path is '/storage/emulated/0/Documents'.  Neither path works when used in my Delphi Android application.  I can no longer see the files in the Documents folder.

Comment: I believe that /'storage/emulated/legacy/Documents' worked at one point, but it no longer works (on the same Android device).

Comment: Solved by Delphi Praxis.: it was a permissions issue.

Comment: You should answer your own answer and check mark it please.